# close all <b-collapse> when clicking on a button (starting visible)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have following problem. I have multiple `b-buttons` connected with `b-collapse`, all are starting **visible** (so they are open).

Now I need to make them `none visible` when the `toggle` from my `parent.vue` will be triggered - so after clicking on my `button` in my `parent.vue` I need to close all, that when I retrigger it and open the complete `collapse` all collapse in my `child.vue` should be closed.

How can I achieve that?

*Parent.vue*

```
<b-button class="col-5" v-b-toggle="'New' + item.id" variant="danger">
<Child :idParent="item.id"/>
```

*Child.vue*

```
<b-collapse visible :id="'New' + idParent">
  
  <b-button v-b-toggle="Toggle1"></b-button>
  <b-collapse visible id="Toggle1"></b-collapse>

  <b-button v-b-toggle="Toggle2"></b-button>
  <b-collapse visible id="Toggle2"></b-collapse>

  <b-button v-b-toggle="Toggle3"></b-button>
  <b-collapse visible id="Toggle3"></b-collapse>

</b-collapse>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to set a 'visible' boolean in the parent, toggled by the button press, and then pass this to the child to use in the button elements. For example:

Parent.vue

```
<b-button class="col-5" v-b-toggle="'New' + item.id" variant="danger" @click="!buttons_visible">
<Child :idParent="item.id" :buttons_visible="buttons_visible" />
```

Child.vue

```
<b-collapse visible :id="'New' + idParent">
  <b-button v-b-toggle="Toggle1"></b-button>
  <b-collapse :visible="buttons_visible" id="Toggle1"></b-collapse>

  <b-button v-b-toggle="Toggle2"></b-button>
  <b-collapse :visible="buttons_visible" id="Toggle2"></b-collapse>

  <b-button v-b-toggle="Toggle3"></b-button>
  <b-collapse :visible="buttons_visible" id="Toggle3"></b-collapse>
</b-collapse>
```